# How to check datagridview column already exists with same Header Text Before adding a new Column in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to add columns dynamically to data grid view using VB.net. But the issue is I need to check that the column name already exists. before adding it if exists I want it to be cancelled automatically. I am using another form to select the Job Nos. which will add as Datagridview Header Text when it saved. () below is the code I am using to add a column to my datagridview. Hope you understand the question. I found some nearby answers in C# unfortunately I am not able to convert those correctly as my C# coding knowledge is little weak.

Thank You!

```
Dim FRMP = FrmEReview.ReviewGrid.Columns
Dim NOHRS As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
FRMP.Add(NOHRS) 
NOHRS.HeaderText = Me.Cmb_CName.Text & "-" & Me.Cmb_DName.Text 
NOHRS.Width = 160
```

Comment: While the syntax is a bit different, the structure of C# code is generally very similar, if not exactly the same, as the equivalent VB code, so you should be able to at least make an attempt for yourself based on C# examples. There are always going to be more C# examples around so, if you have trouble reading them, I would suggest that you download and install [Instant VB](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp-to-vb-converter.html). It will do a consistently better job than any of the online code converters that you also didn't bother to try.

Comment: While it can be done, you really shouldn't be adding columns to a grid on another form. If this is a modal dialogue and it will be closed when this happens, you only need to expose the required data via one or more properties and the other form can get that data when `ShowDialog` returns and add its own columns. If the dialogue won't be closing, you should be raising an event that the other form can handle. It then gets the data from one or more properties and adds its own columns, as before. This is best practice for communicating between forms.

Comment: Are you asking for help writing an if statement?  Would think a far better idea would be to prevent the selection of duplicate job numbers rather than trying to deal with it after the fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious option - the one you should have been able to work out for yourself - is to simply loop through the columns and test the `HeaderText` of each one:

```vb
Dim headerText = $"{Cmb_CName.Text}-{Cmb_DName.Text}"
Dim headerTextFound = False

For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In FrmEReview.ReviewGrid.Columns
    If column.HeaderText = headerText Then
        headerTextFould = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not headerTextFound Then
    '...
End If
```

This is basically the code equivalent of what you'd do manually, which is why you should have been able to do it for yourself, at least mostly.

The not-so-obvious solution for a beginner is to use LINQ. LINQ is basically a means to flatten loops like this, so it leads to far more succinct code:

```vb
Dim headerText = $"{Cmb_CName.Text}-{Cmb_DName.Text}"

If FrmEReview.ReviewGrid.
              Columns.
              Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)().
              All(Function(dgvc) dgvc.HeaderText <> headerText) Then
    '...
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much This worked. Sorry for me been so narrow. which I should be able to solve by my self. Thanks again.!